# PDF page size is not exact the one provided

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I need to create a PDF with iText with a fixed dimensions:

> Height: 95 mm = 3.74 in
>
> Width: 50 mm = 1.96 in

So I've done in the code:

```
float width = mmToPt(95); 
float height = mmToPt(50);
Rectangle rectanglePage = new Rectangle(width, height);
Document document = new Document(rectanglePage, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

where the mmToPt() function is (according to the documentation 70pt=1in=2.54cm):

```
public static float mmToPt(float mm){
    //70pt = 25.4mm
    return ((70f * mm) / 25.4f);
}
```

The problem is that when I open the PDF generated going to File/Properties I can see that it says Page Size 3.64 x 1.91 in. Which is not the exact size I'm setting (it's about 2 or 3 mm shorter - Though it's just a little it's important because the file must have this dimensions).

What can be happening? How can I solve the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's 72 dots == 1 inch, not 70.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't see the most obvious

Comment: Don't you hate that?  I've met some arrogant programmers, but I don't see how they can be with all these machines telling them all thing things they've screwed up.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Utilities class in com.itextpdf.text